# Setting a time picker date

Tags: java, android

EDIT:

Error trying to set hour and minute values on the calender object.

I'm trying to set the time and minute values of a time picker on my app.

I have the time value stored as a string in my database. I have parsed this value to a Date object and now I'm not exactly sure how I can get the hour and minute value to set the picker itself.

I.e if the time was stored at 8.30 PM, I want to set this on the time picker through the onCreate method of my class.

Here's my code so far:

```
     DateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
     try 
    {
    dateToEdit = newFormat.parse(returnedTime);
    } catch (ParseException e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }     


     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.setTime(dateToEdit);
     editTimePicker.setCurrentHour(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
     editTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Log cat showing errors

```
01-29 21:58:47.860: D/AndroidRuntime(269): Shutting down VM
01-29 21:58:47.870: W/dalvikvm(269): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flybase2/com.example.flybase2.AppointmentEditChanges}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.example.flybase2.AppointmentEditChanges.onCreate(AppointmentEditChanges.java:100)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-29 21:58:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: What happens with your existing code?

Comment: @Aaron Kurtzhals Currently nothing. I'm hoping someone can push me in the right direction to showing how I can extract the hour and minute values from my 'dateToEdit' object and set the timepicker with these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Calendar` to get the time out of the date object:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime( dateToEdit );
timePicker.setCurrentHour( cal.get( HOUR_OF_DAY ) );
timePicker.setCurrentMinute( cal.get( MINUTE ) );
```

You'll have to create `timePicker` before doing the above, either by

```
timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById( R.id.my_time_picker );
```

or

```
timePicker = new TimePicker( this );
```

in the second case, you'll then have to add it to your layout somehow.

Comment: Isnt it supposed to `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` and `Calendar.MINUTE`?

Comment: @Ralgha Many thanks for your answer. I have tried the code and have set it to my imports but now im getting an errror when creating the calender object instance. I have added the LogCat to my original post. I seem to be getting an 'unparsable date' error.

Comment: Also to add. I fixed the parsing error as i set my date layout to be "hh:mm" only. Now i still have the error on the actual HOUR and MINUTE setting.

Comment: @Ralgha Sorry i forgot to add that I had done that with my code. Im still getting the crash when actually trying to set the hour and minute of the time picker. I have added my complete code above. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: @Ralgha Thanks again for your response. I have tried both of these methods and am still getting a null pointer exception when I run the code.

Comment: @Ralgha I forgot to add my findviewbyId to the timepicker in the xml! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't store your dates and times as strings in your database (don't forget timezones, ...).

Instead, store the number of milliseconds since the epoch in the GMT timezone (`long` value).

Such time can easily obtained by `Date.getTime()`

You can then use that again to build your dates or calendars again:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(myTimeZone);
cal.setTimeInMillis(myDbTime);
```

I also strongly advise you to leave alone `java.util.Date` and other `java.util.Calendar` in favor of [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).